# Simultaneous/shared internet access between \windows 7 and Ubuntu on vmware workstation

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I am trying to set up hotspot using easyhotspot full distro (Ubuntu acts as host for easyhotspot). I am trying to do this in VMware Workstation 9 with Windows 7 as host. I am able to access internet from Ubuntu with the static ip provided by my ISP. The problem is that when I am connected to internet in Windows 7, I am not able to connect to the internet in Ubuntu. How do share internet with or without Windows ICS to access internet simultaneously in both environments?

Also, I have 2 lans. The second lan is for distributing the internet connection to access points through ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. I just had to configure my first nic (WAN) to be NATed with VMnet0 in the VMware. That's it. I could also make it as Bridged network but I observed that I was not able to access internet simultaneously in both the OS. However, I could achieve that with NAT.